# How to disable background scrolling with mouse wheel while a lightbox plugin is activated?

Tags: javascript, magnific-popup

I'm working on an horizontal scrolling website.
On it, I'm using mousewheel.js plugin (to allow horizontal scroll with mouse wheel) and the magnific-popup plugin.

When someone activates the magnific-popup plugin by clicking on a photo, it opens the photo, as it should be, and background scrollbars are disabled.

But, as I'm using mousewheel.js, the background is still scrollable with mouse wheel.

How would it be possible to disable background scrolling only when magnific-popup is showing a photo ?

Answer (score 3):

I have a similar problem. This decision helped me in part.

```
$('#open_button').magnificPopup({

    type: 'inline',          // Custom settings, never mind
    closeBtnInside: false,   // Custom settings, never mind
    fixedContentPos: false,  // Custom settings, never mind
    fixedBgPos: true,        // Custom settings, never mind

    callbacks: {

        open: function() {                        // When you open the
            $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');  // window, the element
        },                                        // "body" is used "overflow: hidden".

        close: function() {                       // When the window
            $('body').css('overflow', '');        // is closed, the 
        },                                        // "overflow" gets the initial value.

    }

});
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SO. Please add in *what* you did differently, and why it works. Answers like these are typically considered low-quality otherwise.

Comment: Good afternoon, Derek. Sorry, but I'm new here, I do not know how to add another answer. Can you tell me?
I was looking for this solution, I saw that the answer is not closed, and when I found a solution on another site, I decided to help others here.

Answer (score 0):

```
fixedContentPos: true,
overflowY: 'hidden',
```

This should work!